# Is there an ORM-like java-library with runtime-defined tables for building sql queries?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, orm

I have the following problem: We have several different databases on which our program runs, so the exact database-structure is unknown during compile-time. We are now searching for a library which allows us to build query-objects, that can be translated to several SQL-dialects and gives us a plain Query-String.

We search for something similar to regular ORM-Libraries such as Hibernate. We've looked into some of them, but it seems that all of them except tables and columns to be defined at compile-time as a regular java-class. If I'm wrong on this, please correct me.

The basic difference between the ORM approach and ours is, that we don't want to store java-objects in databases, but to generate queries as java-objects. To make my point more clear, I will show you some example code, that should be executable by the library.

```
QueryObject query = new QueryObject();
query.addSelectedTable("customers");
query.addSelectedColumn("customerID");
query.addSelectedColumn("firstname");
query.addCondition("age < 20");
query.addLimit(10);

System.out.println(query.toMySQL()); 
//prints SELECT customerID, firstname FROM customers WHERE age < 20 LIMIT 10;
```

I don't know if such a library exists, but if you know one, I would be happy to know about it.

To be more demanding, there are several other features, that would be great. For example, it should also be able to handle subqueries and other query-types as SELECT. But that would be too much to expect ;-)

Comment: Do you mean CriteriaAPI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out [Squiggle-SQL](https://code.google.com/archive/p/squiggle-sql/)?

Comment: Looks great. I think, this could be exactly what I was looking for. But first I have to take a closer look.

Comment: As a first basis, Squiggle fits perfectly. But it also lackes some features a really need, like LIMIT, HAVING, GROUP BY. It also just features SELECT-queries. But since it is open source, I think we are going to expand it for our needs.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org/) or CrieriaAPi?

Comment: As far as I can tell, both of those libs need to define table structures during compile time. So this isn't what I was looking for, since I need to define the tables/columns during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be 'many' session with there own configuration (hibernateDialect). Maybe re-initializing the (hibernate) session (programatic config) works - never tried that.

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Cayenne](http://cayenne.apache.org/) is an open source Java ORM that supports [generic persistent classes](http://cayenne.apache.org/doc30/generic-persistent-class.html). In runtime you would dynamically define your DB mapping via API or by reverse-engineering the DB schema, and then run queries, getting back generic map-like objects. In fact with this approach you get not just queries, but all other normal ORM features you might expect - lazy relationships, the ability to modify and commit the objects, etc, etc.